# Incorrect .mo file when using Glotpress and Cyrillic strings

Tags: encoding, character

I'm using GlotPress to translate some projects. I've encountered a problem when the translator used this word : "Подписка" the last "а" is a Cyrillic one and not the "regular a".

Here's and example of what is happening : https://i.stack.imgur.com/va38f.png

If I export the .po, open it on poedit, the .mo file is correct (no errors shown), they only appear when using the .mo directly from GlotPress.

I can not ask the translators to avoid the Cyrillic а, also I don't know if this is happening with any other character in any other language. Also I can not ask them to download the file, open it on poedit and save it.

Comment: There is generally nothing special about `а`. Does it happen with other words with `а` ? Does it happen with other words with `а` in the end? Does it happen with other words?